# add watermark to all images uploaded in the site

Tags: hooks, theming, media

I am trying add watermark to all the images uploaded by users. Is there any preprocessor for the same? or any module to achieve it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Module [ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) is a well supported module that can add watermarks for Drupal 5,6,7.  It does this all by caching the image using imagecache.

Comment: I installed this module, but did not get how to configure the watermark part.

Comment: I don't remember completely,  but I"m pretty sure there is 2 setups.  #1. you create the imagecache with the watermark action (like you do for cropping, scaling, etc).   #2 for a node, you go to display fields and select from the dropdown how you want the image to be displayed.   If you are still having trouble let me know

Comment: will try and update u.

Comment: were you able to get it working?

Comment: no.. have to work on it little more